# Auth error in facebook test apps

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I have working facebook application and created test app for it with slightly different functionality.
Administration role can auth on this app and use it, but any created test user or real user added as tester give me error on authentication: "App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login."
Sandbox mode - off.
Site URL, Privacy Policy URL, Contact Email, App Domains is filled and correct.

What I missed?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure there is a contact email under "Settings." Then go to the Status & Review section and click Yes to "make this app and all its live features available to the general public."

Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRuOe_yLWR4